# Converting npArrays to integers

Tags: python, numpy

I have an npArray of npArrays. When we print the npArray, we get

> [[1] [2] [3]]

I want to change this array into an npArray with just integers in the form of

> [1 2 3]

Thank you. The code is below. I already attempted it in there

```
a = np.array([np.array([1]),np.array([2]),np.array([3])])
print(type(a[0]))
for i in range(0,2):
    a[i] = a[i][0]

print(a)
```

Comment: You can use [np.ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) :  `print(a.ravel())`

Answer (score 2):

You can use flatten method

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.array([1]),np.array([2]),np.array([3])])
print(type(a[0]))

print('Original')
print(a)

a = a.flatten()
print('Converted')
print(a)
```

Output :

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Original
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
Converted
[1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

> **`a.flatten()`** or **`a.ravel()`** or **`a.reshape(1,-1)`** or **`a.T`**

You can use any of the following four options:

- `a.flatten()` *EDIT: as @PhilipPurwoko suggested in his solution.*
- `a.ravel()` *EDIT: as @MarkMeyer also suggested in the comments section.*
- `a.reshape(1,-1)`: reshaping to 1-row array
- `a.T`: *transposing will also give you your desired result here as you have a column array and you want it as a row array.*

### Example

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5).reshape(-1, 1)
print(a)

## Output
# [[0]
#  [1]
#  [2]
#  [3]
#  [4]]

a.flatten() 
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

a.ravel()
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

a.reshape(1,-1)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

a.T
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer I was adding another option. Wasn't done yet.

Comment: @green142f You can use any of these four methods.